# Change input to button without touching js

Tags: html

i have html input when enter number and press enter it will change the image size

```
<input type="text" size="2" id="change-width">
```

now i want to turn the input into button or a icon when press it will change the image size like input did.the function is with the id name but i dont want to change stuff there.

is there anyway i could do this by only html and wont touch any js ?

i already tried

```
<button type="submit" value="25" id="change-width">A4 size</button>
```

Comment: No, HTML is not programming language, it's markup language, there is no _logic_ part in it.

Comment: Yeah i understand but if input a value could send the data into it, could somehow a button do so ?

Comment: Buttons are intended not to send any information when submitting.